# button_to using GET method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working through Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Edition (Rails 3.2+) and I am somewhat confused by the button_to method. The book as well as every other google search I have done says the button_to uses a POST request. However, when I inspect the page, the button_to appears to be using a GET method.

Now, I could have this wrong, but I come from a php background and a POST method always meant that the data was being passed to the server without the url and accessed through an array server side:

```
$_POST['form_item']
```

Furthermore, a GET request meant passing data through the url:

```
someurl.com/somepage?DATA=data_value
```

Using this button_to code:

```
  <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product_id) %>
```

This becomes the form output:

```
<form action="/line_items?product_id=4" class="button_to" method="post">
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vGT1scGqasbQAMxYwofXHCM62MfSyM/pNty69Ep5t38=" />
</div>
</form>
```

the action on this form appears to be passing data through the url (?product_id=4). Although I can clearly see the "method='post'", isnt this a using GET?

Comment: @mischa thank you for the clarification. Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FancyDancy says, it's still a post request even though the information gets passed through the URL. Rails doesn't make a distinction between `$_GET` and `$_POST`. It only has the equivalent of `$_REQUEST`: `params`. So it doesn't really matter if the product_id gets passed via the URL or via a hidden form field. In both cases you can get it via `params[:product_id]`.

Answer (score 8):

By default, it uses POST method. If you need GET, just type it as:

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product_id), :method => :get %>
```

You can check rails' logs and verify that it's really POST request.

Answer (score 1):

A POST request can also have a QUERY_STRING. The problem is, that your `line_items_path` has no parameter in the path called `:product_id`, thats why the helper adds this parameter to the QUERY_STRING. If you want to have it in the path, check your routes (`rake routes`), there must be something like

```
POST      /line_items/:product_id(.:format)     line_items
```